# return boolean or Observable<boolean> from canActivate

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have this requirement where I have to load some application settings first and then get the user information. So here is how the code currently is-

```
    canActivate(route, state):boolean/Observable<boolean>{

       return this.getSettings().map(response=>
    {
      this.data1=response;
      this.getUser()
    }).catch(error=>
    {
      this.error=error<any>;
    })
    )

}
```

Here the route that has been protected by the guard depends on the booelan state of `getSettings()` but I do not want that. What I want instead is to depend on the boolean state of `getUser()`.

`getUser()` is called from inside the success callback of `getSettings()` because it depends on some of the data coming from `getSettings()`.

Here's `getUser()`:

```
 getUser(){
    return this.service.getUser().
    subscribe(
    response=>//do some stuff
    ,
    error=> this.router.navigate(['errorpage'])
    )

}
```

I tried separating the code of `getAppSettings` in a separate `settingsService` and then did this in `canActivate`-

```
canActivate(route, state):boolean/Observable<boolean>/Promise<boolean>{
    return this.settingsService.getSettings().toPromise().then(
                   function(auth:boolean){
                                        if(!auth){
                                        return Promise.resolve(false);
                                        }else{
                                        return this.service.getUser().
                                                  subscribe(
                                                   response=>{//do some stuff

                                                     return Promise.resolve(true);},
                                                   error=> {this.router.navigate(['errorpage']), Promise.resolve(false)}
    )
   }
  }
 )
}
```

But the above code again doesn't let me return a `boolean/Promise<boolean>/Observable<boolean>` from `getUser` to the `canActivate` function. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You need to flatten it out: `return this.service.getSettings().flatMap(settings => this.service.getUser(...)).map(user => ...);`.

Comment: are you sure this is gonna work cause I still see you returning `getSettings` boolean state instead of `getUser` boolean. How is it different from what I did?

Comment: Where do you see that? The result of that chain is an observable of: whatever you want from the user; that we got from calling getUser with whatever you want from the settings; that we got from getSettings. Try it out, use `map` and `flatMap` to convert one observable to another rather than trying to `subscribe` everywhere. This is a much more natural way of working with RxJS. Without a [mcve] it's hard to say how to convert your specific code, but this is the approach I think you should use.

Comment: Ok let me clarify. I want canActivate to depend on the boolean state of `getUser` and not on `loadSettings`.

Comment: But `loadSettings` must be called before getUser as getUser depends on some parameters received from loadSettings.

Comment: thats why wrapping the `getUser` call inside `loadSettings` coz if not done this way data from loadSettings wont be available to getUser.

Comment: I hope i am clear now.

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify. Don't pile a bunch of information way down here in the comments.